# How to center a checkbox input to sibling text inputs that have label on top?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a checkbox input to its text input siblings. The text inputs have label on top of them and the checkbox label is to the side of it.

Using flexbox, it doesn't work because align-items: center; centers it to the entire height including the label:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    label
  </label>
</div>
```

But I want the checkbox to be in the center of the text box, something like this:

[image]

What is a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: This is an optical approach https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/o246ty9j/ 

Comment: Does this need to be CSS only? I have provided a solution below with the help of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. I just udpated your align-items property and it looks same as the picture you shared.

```css
.wrapper {
   align-items: end;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* Three columns */
   gap: 10px; /* Gap between grid items */
}

label span {
  display: block;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Label: Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic...
</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    label
  </label>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Hi. Where did you hear about the align-items `end`? 

Comment: I think it only works in this case by chance because the heights happen to match the position of the `align-items` and will not work for different heights

Comment: @deEr, You can check from w3school. We can use align-item `end` property with grid. btw I know this because I have been using it for a long time.

Comment: @pileup, So you mean your label can be increase and it can be more than one line ?

Comment: Considering your concern @pileup, I added more text in one of your label and It doesn't break so please check updated code now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with CSS, because it is already centered with respect to the flex axis. Javascript may help. You can check by changing heights of the 2nd label or the 2nd input, it works.

```js
let iDS = ["total", "chkBox", "inp"];

let heights = iDS.map((id)=>(document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight))

let topPad= (heights[0]-heights[2]);

document.getElementById("chkBox").style.paddingTop = topPad + "px";
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="total" class="wrapper">
  <label>
        <span>label:</span>
        <input type="text">
      </label>
  <label>
        <span>label:</span>
        <input id="inp" type="text">
      </label>
  <label id="chkBox">
        <input type="checkbox">
        label
      </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a speedy solution for you on this occassion could be to align the items in your flex box layout at `flex-end` instead. Of course, as suggested in other comments, this might not be scalable as it depends on what else you intend to add to the form.
I hope this is what you were trying to do and I haven't misunderstood. Happy coding!

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

label span {
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    label
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A universal solution can be the use of `display:grid` + `grid-template-rows:subgrid`.
Here's an example (I'll just change your html a bit):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 160px);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 2px 8px;
}

label {
  display: grid;
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  min-width: 0;
}

.checkbox {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}

input {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>label:</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox"> label
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```